# How to serve an App Engine website's /static/ directory content from Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to run an Node.js app on the GCP, while having only the scripts uploaded to the App Engine.
All the static files are to be placed inside a bucket in Cloud Storage, for easier manipulation.
While the app is running on https://netwell.digital, all the static files are to be found inside https://netwell.digital/static/.

So far I have found contradicting info on this and Google Cloud Platform itself only goes as far as:

> You can now [access your static assets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files) via https://storage.googleapis.com//static/...

Is there a way to have the bucket mapped as this /static/ directory of an App Engine application?

Comment: Why don't you just use the bucket url for the image directly?  Or a lookup table, so when the page requests `https://sparkx.online/static/...`, it is replaced by the bucket url?

Comment: Pointing to the bucket url directly is the most cumbersome and least elegant way linking to static resources inside a bucket I could think of. Repeating the full absolute `https://storage.googleapis.com/..` for every resource inside every page and css is quite nasty.
Replacing a placeholder string with the bucket URL server-side is just as unreasonable, plus it cannot be done with files such as CSSs and scripts inside the bucket and doing that client-side is totally a no go.
I can't imagine there is no way to have a bucket mapped as a directory for an App Engine app.

Comment: Update: A way to do someting similar is to create a CNAME record on the domain to point sometinhg like "static.netwell.digital" to "storage.googleapis.com" and so being able to access the bucket files on static.netwell.digital/<unique-bucket-name>, but is there really no way to place static files in the traditional directory structure within the same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you want it to function is possible using [Cloud Storage bucket to host a static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). But you have to choose serving your website from App Engine or a bucket. As you find the documentation [serving static file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files) it is the way you access, it seems not possible how you wanted it to be.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of all this. You are actually summarizing my problem. :) I just can't believe that some things, such as basic management and deployment of static resources can get so complicated. I was expecting GCP to make my life easier, but managing own server seems to be a better option a this point, for many reasons.